# ADB Driver for Sony Xperia E4 (E2105)

Tags: android, adb

I'm struggling to start developing on my phone. By the official steps the ADB drivers should be installed by installing a PC Companion software, however all I get is a dialog saying that the debug mode is active but that I should look for the drivers under the following link http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/ but my device is not listed there so I'm stuck.

[image]

In the device manager my phone is showing as

[image]

If anyone has a clue, please do let me know, I'm using Win 7/64bit

Comment: would love to but can't do it at this point

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Comment: @Alex but shouldn't it first show as an ADB device in my Device Manager

Comment: The device won't appear in the `ADB Devices` category without the proper driver installed. In your `Device Manager` window you can see the `MTP` interface properly listed under `Portable Devices`. But the `ADB Interface` is listed under `Other devices`

Answer (score 1):

> When connect Xperia to PC open Device Manager -> Other devices
>   ->Android ADB interface -> update driver -> search in PC - wait until all manufacturers are loaded ->choose Sony or Sony Ericsson -> find
>   ADB interface driver -> read ->

[more information about this problem in official support forum](http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-E-E-dual/ADB-driver-XPERIA-E/td-p/290337)

Comment: I've seen the thread, my problem is that I don't see my phone as Android ADB interface, rather as E2105, I've pasted the devices manager image

Comment: Do this for Other Devices -> E2105. This devices has no driver, but must have ADB driver. So after installation it will became Android ADB interface

Comment: I've tried with updating drivers, the list the guy adresses in his answer is never rendered for me